# generalize pattern with intersection of restrictions?

Tags: sparql, owl

**I'm interested in finding diagnosis codes for variants of diabetes (or any other enumerated disease), axiomatically excluding some diseases that are more accurately diabetes-related *syndromes*.**

I use the **Monarch Disease Ontology** *(MonDO)* as my authority on the modelling of diseases and the codes that indicate them in an electronic medical record (like **ICD** or **SNOMED** in some countries.)

I have been retrieving "all variants of a disease" with `rdfs:subClassOf*` triples.  The MonDO model seems pretty good, but sometimes it seems a little overinclusive, and I would like to axiomatically omit some of the subClass relations.

For example, **[H Syndrome](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0011273)** is asserted to be a `rdfs:subClassOf*` **[diabetes](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0005015)**, but as a syndrome, it includes many features other than the essence of diabetes (elevated blood sugar levels for extended periods of time.)  The `ask` below shows how I could `minus` this particular disease out of a query about types of diabetes, based on the fact that it has syndromic and genetic modifications.

**How can I look for diseases with syndromic modifications in a general way, anticipating that the `owl:Restrictions` may not be composed in a consistent way?**  There could be more (or fewer) intersections, `rds:subClassOf` might be used instead of `owl:equivalentClass`...

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
prefix H_Synd: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0019589>
prefix hasMod: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002573>
prefix syndromePres: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0021127>
prefix genetic: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0021152>
ask where {
    H_Synd: owl:equivalentClass ?ec .
    ?ec owl:intersectionOf ?i1 .
    ?i1 rdf:first|rdf:rest ?ilpart .
    ?ilpart rdf:first|rdf:rest ?ilpartf , ?ilpartr .
    ?ilpartf rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
             owl:onProperty hasMod: ;
             owl:someValuesFrom syndromePres: .
    ?ilpartr rdf:first|rdf:rest ?ilpartrpart .
    ?ilpartrpart rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty hasMod: ;
                 owl:someValuesFrom genetic: .
}
```

Comment: Do you mean multiple conjuncts in an intersection? If so, did you try the property path `rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest* [ rdf:first ?conjunct ]]]` which should at least give the reference to each node in an intersection, either for named classes or the "root node " of a property restriction. Could also be written shorter with `( rdfs:subClassOf / owl:intersectionOf / rdf:rest* / rdf:first ) ) ?conjunct`

Comment: by the way, what is the expected result of your query? FALSE?

Comment: the result of the ask is TRUE... `H Syndrome` does have the specified pattern including syndromic and genetic modifications.  No, I haven't tried paths over rdf:first or rest.  Maybe that is most or all of what I need.

Comment: hm, ok. I tried it in the Ontobee SPARQL interface, and it returns `FALSE`. It's probably the wrong SPARQL endpoint then.

Comment: yes, you should try the pattern `rdf:rest*/rdf:first` then. It's the common pattern to handle lists which in fact is what the OWL intersection is based on in the RDF mapping

Comment: Whoa, OntoBee and I must be using different versions of mondo.owl.  The object of the last `owl:someValuesFrom` is different.  I updated my query to return TRUE from OntoBee.  Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

*As usual, this is based on generous comments:*

The property path query below retrieves 4000+ syndromic disease from my repository.  I haven't gotten it to run on OntoBee yet.

Concerns:

1. I thought I should use a more inclusive property path, like `(rdf:first|rdf:rest|rdfs:subClassOf)*`, but that kept running for several minutes before I aborted.  Obviously the `?pre rdf:first* ?ilpartf` gets some useful classes, but `?pre rdf:first ?ilpartf` pattern only gets 36 blank nodes.
2. I can get the same results from a simple `rdfs:subClassOf*` query.  MonDO contains the OWL axiom below.  If it has already been reasoned, I'm just getting disease classes that have been directly asserted as syndromic diseases
3. The thousands of syndromic disease classes are all bound to a single pair of `{ ?pre ?sub }`.  The other 35 `?pre` blank nodes aren't bound to any `?sub` class other than themselves.

#### Syndromic disease axiom

```
disease or disorder and (has
      modifier some 
      has a syndromic presentation)
```

#### `rdfs:subClassOf*` query:

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
select * where {
    ?s rdfs:subClassOf* obo:MONDO_0002254 .
}
```

#### property path query:

```sql
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
prefix H_Synd: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0019589>
prefix hasMod: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002573>
prefix syndromePres: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0021127>
prefix genetic: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/MONDO_0021152>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * where {
    graph obo:mondo.owl {
        # ?pre (rdf:first|rdf:rest|rdfs:subClassOf)* ?ilpartf .
        ?pre rdf:first* ?ilpartf .
        ?ilpartf rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty hasMod: ;
                 owl:someValuesFrom syndromePres: .
        ?sub rdfs:subClassOf* ?pre .
        optional {
            ?sub  rdfs:label ?l
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the same (nor do I understood what you really try to find :D), but I'd use this `select ?sub ?l where {
    
        ?sub rdfs:subClassOf*/(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)? ?ilpartf .
        ?ilpartf rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty hasMod: ;
                 owl:someValuesFrom syndromePres: .
        
        optional {
            ?sub  rdfs:label ?l
        }   
    }`

Comment: thanks.  what's the difference between separating predicates with a slash (/) versus a vertical pipe (|)?

Comment: `/` means a sequence path, e.g. `?s :p/:q ?o` means `?s` and `?o` are connected via a path with the edge `:p` followed by edge `:q`, i.e. here in the example there is an intermediate node and it's the same as `?s :p ?tmp. ?tmp :q ?o`. `|` on the other hand means an alternative, e.g. `?s :p|:q ?o` will return all pairs `(?s, ?o)` with having either `:p` or `:q` as predicate. It's basically the same as `{?s :p ?o} UNION {?s :q ?q}` - indeed, with property paths you can do very complex expressions, especially once you use the `*` operator.

Comment: Property Path [syntax is pretty well documented](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths)...